# Add missing value in column with value from row above

Tags: r

Every week I a incomplete dataset for a analysis. That looks like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a","","","b",""), 
             var2 = c("x","y","z","x","z"))
```

Some var1 values are missing. The dataset should end up looking like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a","a","a","b","b"), 
             var2 = c("x","y","z","x","z"))
```

Currently I use an Excel macro to do this. But this makes it harder to automate the analysis. From now on I would like to do this in R. But I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks for your help.

**QUESTION UPDATE AFTER COMMENT**

var2 is not relevant for my question. The only thing I am trying to is. Get from df1 to df2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a","","","b",""))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a","a","a","b","b"))
```

Comment: I don't understand the pattern you are using to replace missing values with. Do you want to replace the first set of blanks with 'a' until 'b' then replace blanks with 'b' until 'c' and so on...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. var2 isn't relevant for question at all. I will update my question.

Comment: I the the tidyr package v0.3.0 `fill()` is added. This is exact the thing  I wanted.

Comment: Great question! Will definitely come back to this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tidyr packages has the `fill()` function which does the trick.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a",NA,NA,"b",NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 %>% fill(var1)
```

Answer (score 25):

Here is one way of doing it by making use of run-length encoding (`rle`) and its inverse `rle.inverse`:

```
fillTheBlanks <- function(x, missing=""){
  rle <- rle(as.character(x))
  empty <- which(rle$value==missing)
  rle$values[empty] <- rle$value[empty-1] 
  inverse.rle(rle)
}

df1$var1 <- fillTheBlanks(df1$var1)
```

The results:

```
df1

  var1 var2
1    a    x
2    a    y
3    a    z
4    b    x
5    b    z
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks Andrie! I adapted this to my needs and produced a monster (possibly dangerous), but for the record: https://pastebin.com/82kvNp1D

Answer (score 20):

Here is a simpler way:

```
library(zoo)
df1$var1[df1$var1 == ""] <- NA
df1$var1 <- na.locf(df1$var1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way which is slightly shorter and doesn't coerce to character:

```
Fill <- function(x,missing="")
{
  Log <- x != missing
  y <- x[Log]
  y[cumsum(Log)]
}
```

Results:

```
# For factor:
Fill(df1$var1)
[1] a a a b b
Levels:  a b

# For character:
Fill(as.character(df1$var1))
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my unfill function, encontered same problem, hope will help.

```
unfill <- function(df,cols){
  col_names <- names(df)
  unchanged <- df[!(names(df) %in% cols)]
  changed <- df[names(df) %in% cols] %>%
    map_df(function(col){
      col[col == col %>% lag()] <- NA
      col
    })
  unchanged %>% bind_cols(changed) %>% select(one_of(col_names))
}
```